# Force UTF8 env variable Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

Hi I have a problem with bitbucket plugin,

When I want build pull request I have this error :

> Could not set the value of environment variable 'CHANGE_AUTHOR': could not convert string to current locale

I identified the problem. Now I want set encoding of env.CHANGE_AUTHOR variable.

When PullRequest is ok value of CHANGE_AUTHOR :

```
CHANGE_AUTHOR = St?phane
```

When PullRequest is not ok value of CHANGE_AUTHOR :

```
CHANGE_AUTHOR = Stéphane
```

Can you help me to set UTF8 ?

Answer (score 0):

You should add this JVM param to your Jenkins starting script (JAVA_TOOLS_OPTIONS):

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```